# Setting paper size for PDF output in bookdown with tufte-book

Tags: r, bookdown

In _output.yml, the following actually sets the paper size correctly:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:   
  pandoc_args: [    
   "-V", "papersize=a4"    
  ]
```

But when I want to use tufte_book, the papersize argument has no effect, and the output in in letter size no matter what:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  base_format: tufte::tufte_book
  pandoc_args: [
   "-V", "papersize=a4"
   ]
```

How do I override the default paper size in tufte_book?

Answer (score 6):

You have to specify this as

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  base_format: tufte::tufte_book
  pandoc_args: [
   "-V", "papersize=a4paper"
   ]
```

I found this only by looking at the resulting `.tex` file. The reason is in the used templates. The [Tufte templte](https://github.com/rstudio/tufte/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/tufte_handout/resources/tufte-handout.tex#L1) includes `$if(papersize)$$papersize$,$endif$` in the options to the document class, while the [default template](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex#L1) uses `$if(papersize)$$papersize$paper,$endif$` with a literal `paper`.

BTW, you can also defines this in  `index.Rmd` as

```
---
[...]
papersize: a4paper
---
```